# Admin config with extendable amount of fields

Tags: magento-1.9, system.xml, system-config

I want to create an admin config with "exception dates".

Since the number of these dates can vary, I cannot just put a constant number of input fields in the config.

Is there a way to automatically add more fields or have a button to add extra fields? Then perhaps collecting the values into an array...

Comment: I followed the above answer as it is for my module, everything is working fine, even saved values are also storing in database, but the thing is when I reopen it in admin side later the selected dropdown is not showing on the screen. Why is it so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add an "Add field" button to you config field, you can use this:

> app/code/POOL/My/Module/etc/system.xml

```
<delay_by_country translate="label">
    <label>Email delay per country</label>
    <frontend_model>mx_custom_emails/adminhtml_config_countryDays</frontend_model>
    <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array</backend_model>
    <sort_order>110</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
    <depends><enabled>1</enabled></depends>
</delay_by_country>
```

See `<frontend_model>` and `<backend_model>`. Frontend model is responsable for you system config output and backend model `adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array` to store data as serialized array.

For set frontend model you have to create an new block class to generate the field form.

> app\code\local\Mx\CustomEmails\Block\Adminhtml\Config\CountryDays.php

```
class Mx_CustomEmails_Block_Adminhtml_Config_CountryDays extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Array_Abstract
{
    protected $_itemRenderer;

    /**
     * Fix for ignored "depends enabled"
     * See: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15500/configuration-depends-with-front-and-backend-model
     */
    public function _toHtml()
    {
        return '<div id="' . $this->getElement()->getId(). '">' . parent::_toHtml() . '</div>';
    }

    public function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('country_id', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('mx_custom_emails')->__('Country'),
            'renderer' => $this->_getRenderer(),
        ));
        $this->addColumn('email_delay', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('mx_custom_emails')->__('Email Delay in Days'),
            'style' => 'width:100px',
            'class' => 'validate-zero-or-greater input-text',
        ));

        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('mx_custom_emails')->__('Add');
    }

    protected function _getRenderer()
    {
        if (!$this->_itemRenderer) {
            $this->_itemRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'mx_custom_emails/adminhtml_config_form_field_country',
                '',
                array('is_render_to_js_template' => true)
            );
        }
        return $this->_itemRenderer;
    }

    protected function _prepareArrayRow(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $row->setData(
            'option_extra_attr_' . $this->_getRenderer()
                ->calcOptionHash($row->getData('country_id')),
            'selected="selected"'
        );
    }
}
```

Within the `_getRenderer()` method you define another block class that's responable for rendering a column *(in my case a dropdown for all countries)*

> app\code\local\Mx\CustomEmails\Block\Adminhtml\Config\Form\Field\Country.php

```
class Mx_CustomEmails_Block_Adminhtml_Config_Form_Field_Country extends Mage_Core_Block_Html_Select
{
    /**
     * Prepare HTML output
     *
     * @return Mage_Core_Block_Html_Select
     */
    public function _toHtml()
    {
        $options = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_config_source_country')
            ->toOptionArray();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $this->addOption($option['value'], $option['label']);
        }

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Set field name
     *
     * @param string $value
     */
    public function setInputName($value)
    {
        return $this->setName($value);
    }
}
```

To access the serialized config data you can do this *(just as example from an observer, you have to replace config path and add your logic)*:

```
$delay = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales_email/mx_custom_emails/delay_by_country');
# important line
$delay = unserialize($delay);
if (is_array($delay) || sizeof($delay)) {
    $shippingAddressCountryId = $order->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId();
    # important lines
    foreach ($delay as $row) {
        if ($shippingAddressCountryId == $row['country_id']) {
            return $row['email_delay'];
        }
    }
}
```

Finally cou have to create your modules XML file and a config.xml where you define helper (for translation), block and model classes:

> app/code/POOL/My/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<blocks>
    <mx_custom_emails>
        <class>Mx_CustomEmails_Block</class>
    </mx_custom_emails>
</blocks>
<helpers>
    <mx_custom_emails>
        <class>Mx_CustomEmails_Helper</class>
    </mx_custom_emails>
</helpers>
<models>
    <mx_custom_emails>
        <class>Mx_CustomEmails_Model</class>
    </mx_custom_emails>
</models>
```

---

You can also create fields/groups and sections dynamically ... therefor i recommend reading [Create system config section with dynamic number of fields](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.de/2013/02/create-system-config-section-with.html)  @ [Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius) blog.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the comprehensive answer!